# Hibernate: Value generated by SQL query

Tags: sql, hibernate, insert, generated

I want Hibernate 3.3.0 to generate a value by performing a `SELECT` query before `INSERT` (`persist()`). Which would work like this:

```
@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
@GenerateSQL("SELECT RANDOM() * 2")
private int number;
```

I've had a look at `@Generated()`, that's good for `TRIGGER`s. I don't want to introduce a trigger.

I also looked at `@Formula`, that's read-only.

So, what's the right combination of annotations? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I want Hibernate 3.3.0 to generate a value by performing a SELECT query before INSERT

I don't think this is supported.

**Alternative #1:** you could maybe perform the SELECT as part of the "create" logic, directly in your code.

**Alternative #2:** use an Hibernate Interceptor, provide a reference to the `SessionFactory` and perform the SELECT during `onSave` from the Interceptor.

> So, what's the right combination of annotations?

Setting defaults is actually not well supported (see [HHH-4341](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-4341)) and the easiest solution would be IMO to define a DEFAULT value at the column level. That would be my **Alternative #3**. Below an example:

```
@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
@Column(insertable=false, columnDefinition="INT DEFAULT 20") 
private int someNumber;
```

I don't know if this is an option for you and I'm not sure if using `RANDOM()` in the DEFAULT would be supported by the database (how could `RANDOM() * 2` become an `int` by the way?).

Comment: Ad #1 - Well, I guess I will end up with this. But that needs me to lift the transaction to higher level of abstraction.

Ad `RANDOM()` vs. `int` - ok, you got me :) The real use case is generation of invoice numbers which is not simply a sequence (cancelled invoices etc.)

Comment: @Ondra I figured it was an example :) but I see. I don't have better suggestions though.